# EVM opcodes for Boolean AND operations

Tags: solidity, evm, opcode

What opcodes does the EVM use in performing boolean AND (&&) operations

Answer (score 0):

It's probably using the AND (0x16) one.

Comment: but the AND (0x16) is denoted as bitwise AND. https://www.evm.codes/#16?fork=shanghai

Comment: Well, what are bools and what happens when you bitwise AND two one-bit values? @EmmanuelAnah